# role based search permission using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have implemented one spa application using angular. first page is login paage where am setting my current user as admin.

```
       var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

        $rootScope.globals = {
            currentUser: {
                username: username,// Jason
                authdata: authdata // abcd#
            }
        };
      }
```

and second page is a type based search page where i show the data based on user input search.

```
 <div ng-controller = "SearchController">


    <div class="bar">
        <!-- Create a binding between the searchString model and the text field -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter Planet Name" />
    </div>

    <ul>
        <li ng-show='searchString' ng-repeat="i in items | filter:searchString">

            <p>{{i.name}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

so my doubt here is how to allow my admin user can make  more than 20 times searches in a minute .if current user is not admin, then they should not search more then 20 times a minute.

Comment: you mention roles, but nothing about a backend or API? How are the roles managed? How do you know what the users role is?

Comment: I mean to say I need to set permission to a particular user.